# GPS turn-by-turn navigation software for Windows 7

Tags: windows, linux, gps, navigation

I'm looking for a navigation software that runs on Windows 7 or on Linux and can use a NMEA GPS (or `gpsd` under Linux) to provide turn-by-turn navigation, with a 3D view.

License doesn't matter as long as it isn't extremely expensive.

Comment: You can also use "garmin mobile pc" or "Sygic fleet 14" these are very good navigation programs for windows 7. i use a carpc with windows 7 and centrafuse and i'm using sygic and garmin for navigation.